# How retreive the pressed key and update the Edit

Tags: winapi

I have an Edit and I wanna make caracter lowercase when the user press on SHIFT and Upper case in the SHIFT is not pressed (so Kind of opposite of the current behavior).

I did the follwing code, but I stack on how could I update the Edit with the pressed key.

is there any help?

Here the part of my windowProc

```
case WM_CHAR:
    {
        if (HIWORD(wParam) == EN_UPDATE)
        {
            if (ED_FLT_CODE == LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                if ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000) == 0x8000)
                {                       
                    MessageBox(0, "shift", "", 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `EN_UPDATE` is not a parameter of `WM_CHAR`. The code you showed is meant for `WM_COMMAND` instead

Answer (score 0):

if we want modify behavior of standard edit control - all what we need - subclass it window procedure and on [`WM_CHAR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276(v=vs.85).aspx) message, replace `wParam` (*The character code of the key*) to lower or upper case (invert) before call default window procedure for edit. we not need any `GetKeyState` or `EN_UPDATE`

for example:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK SubEditWindowProc(HWND hWnd,
                                 UINT uMsg,
                                 WPARAM wParam,
                                 LPARAM lParam,
                                 UINT_PTR uIdSubclass,
                                 DWORD_PTR /*dwRefData*/
                                 )
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CHAR:
        if (IsCharLowerW((WCHAR)wParam))
        {
            CharUpperBuffW((PWSTR)&wParam, 1);
        }
        else if (IsCharUpperW((WCHAR)wParam))
        {
            CharLowerBuffW((PWSTR)&wParam, 1);
        }
        break;
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, SubEditWindowProc, uIdSubclass);
        break;
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

may be instead [`CharUpperBuff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647475(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`CharLowerBuff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647468(v=vs.85).aspx) need use [`LCMapString[Ex]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318702(v=vs.85).aspx) for some  languages, however for most  languages [`CharUpperBuff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647475(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`CharLowerBuff`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647468(v=vs.85).aspx) is enough

Comment: `CharUpperBuff` and `CharLowerBuff` aren't linguistically sensitive, whereas `LCMapString[Ex]` are.